# Is $f(\theta) = 1 - \alpha \sin{\theta}$ an odd function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, curves, even-and-odd-functions

Consider equations in polar coordinates of the form

$$r = f(\theta) = 1 - \alpha \sin{\theta}$$

When I plot a few of these polar functions, I always get a graph that is symmetric relative to the $y$ axis, indicating that $f(\theta)$ is in fact odd.

Is $f(\theta)$ an odd function?

$$f(-\theta)=1-\alpha\sin{(-\theta)}$$

Since $\sin{(-\theta)}=-\sin{(\theta)}$

$$f(-\theta)=1+\alpha\sin{(\theta)}$$

$$-f(-\theta)=-1-\alpha\sin{(\theta)}=-(1+\alpha\sin{(\theta)}) \neq 1-\alpha\sin{(\theta)}=f(\theta)$$

Is $f(\theta)$ odd, in which case how do I show this? Or is there some edge case where it's not odd?

Comment: First: symmetry about the $y$-axis in cartesian coordinates means the function is *even*, not odd. Second: when you plot in polar coordinates, the "y"-axis is not the line $\theta=0$; it is the line $\theta=\pi/2$. Symmetry about the "y"-axis correspond to $f(\pi/2-\theta)=f(\pi/2+\theta)$, not to $f(\theta)=f(-\theta)$.

Comment: "I always get a graph that is symmetric relative to the $y$ axis, indicating that $f(\theta)$ is in fact odd." ---- This implication is invalid.  Why do you think this?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am using polar coordinates, so symmetry of the graph about the y axis is associated with an odd polar function (an even cartesian function).

Comment: You said "odd function"; an odd function is one whose graph is symmetric about the origin. If you meant something else, then you should say what you mean.

Comment: $f(\pi/2 -\theta) = 1-\alpha\sin(\pi/2-\theta) = 1 - \alpha\cos\theta = 1-\alpha\sin(\pi/2 + \theta)= f(\pi/2+\theta)$. Now think about what that means in the graph of $r=f(\theta)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm going through the book Calculus by Spivak. In Ch 4, appendix 3 on polar coordinates, there is the following problem: "Describe the general features of the graph of f in polar coordinates if i) f is even ii) f is odd iii) $f(\theta) = f(\theta+\pi)$". The answer for ii) is that the graph is symmetric relative to the y-axis. The answer for iii) is that the graph is symmetric relative to the origin.

Comment: *If* $f(\theta)=-f(-\theta)$, then the graph of $r=f(\theta)$ will satisfy the symmetry. But this is not an "if and only if" the same way that it works for cartesian coordinates, because the same point on the plane may be obtained in multiple ways in graphs of functions in polar coordinates, while this is not the case in cartesian rectangular coordinates (which are required to pass the vertical line test; this is not true for polar graphs). So you can obtain a graph symmetric about the $y$-axis in ways *other than* by having $f$ be odd; the problem does not assert it is necessary.

Comment: In particular, a function $f$ that satisfies $f((\pi/2)-\theta) = f((\pi/2)+\theta)$, such as this one, will be symmetric about the $y$-axis even if $f$ does not satisfy $-f(-\theta)=f(\theta)$.

Answer (score 4):

No, the function $f$ is not odd. But, yes, the image of the curve $\theta\mapsto c(\theta)=f(\theta)(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis. That's so because$$c(\pi-\theta)=f(\theta)(-\cos\theta,\sin\theta),$$which is the reflection of $c(\theta)$ on the $y$-axis. So, when $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, for every point $(x,y)$ from its range, $(-x,y)$ also belongs to its range. And the same thing occurs on $[\pi,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

Odd functions: $f(-x)=-f(x)$

Let's try this odd function statement with yours: Assuming function $f$ is odd,
$$f(-x)=-f(x)\\
f(-\theta)=-[1+\alpha \sin(\theta)]\\
[1+\alpha \sin(-\theta)]=-[1+\alpha \sin(\theta)]\\
1-\alpha \sin(\theta) =-1-\alpha \sin(\theta)
$$

Adding $\alpha \sin(\theta)$ to either side, we get: $1 =-1$. Now we know that $1 \neq -1$, therefore $f(\theta)=1+\alpha \sin(\theta)$ is not an odd function.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ cannot be an odd function. In fact, $f(-\theta)=1+\alpha sin(\theta)=\alpha sin(\theta)-1=-f(\theta)$ if and only if $1=-1$.

Comment: You are plotting in the $(\theta,r)$ plane as if they were rectangular coordinates?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin OP is literally asking whether $f$ is odd, in which case the coordinates don't matter.  I think OP may be asking the wrong question, but there's nothing technically wrong here.

Comment: I just looked the question if the map $f(\theta)=1-\alpha sin(\theta)$ is an odd map. Am I wrong?

Comment: @BrianMoehring: I agree the coordinates don't matter to answer the question, but testing whether $f(-\theta)=-f(\theta)$ would not be a correct test of odd-ness if you are using polar coordinates. That is, the *test used* does depend on which coordinates you are using.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have never seen odd-ness of a function in one set of coordinates refer to a point symmetry over the origin in a different set of coordinates, but if you're saying symmetries in $(r,\theta)$ don't necessarily become symmetries in $(x,y)$, then I think we all agree.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x) = 1 - \alpha \sin{(x)}$ in Cartesian coordinates.
Though $\alpha\sin{(x)}$ is an odd function, $1-\alpha\sin{(x)}$ is not, as shown by Mateus Figueiredo's answer.

Note also that shifting $\alpha\sin{(x)}$ to the left by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ makes it equal to $\cos{(x)}$, which is an even function.

Now let's consider the same function, but representing a polar coordinate

$$r=f(\theta)=1-\alpha\sin{(\theta)}$$

In Cartesian coordinates, the condition for symmetry about the y-axis was $f(x)=-f(-x)$.

In polar coordinates I am not quite sure what the general condition is, but here are two ways that a polar function $f(\theta)$ implies a graph that is symmetric relative to the y-axis:

1. $f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$ is even, as noted by Arturo Magidin.
2. $f$ is odd

Note the following

- Given a point in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)=(f(\theta),\theta)$ what can we say about $(-r,\theta)$?

$$(-r,\theta)=(r,\theta+\pi)=(f(\theta),\theta+\pi)\tag{1}$$

**Proof of $1$**

Let $\theta_1>0$ be a constant.

The lines $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} + \theta_1$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta_1$ are symmetric relative to the y-axis. A given $r$ polar coordinate specifies the same $y$ coordinate on both lines. The corresponding pair of points, one on each line, with this $y$ coordinate are symmetric relative to the y axis.

$$y = r \sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \pm \theta_1\right )}=r\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \theta_1\right )}$$

$$x=r \cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \pm \theta_1\right )}=\pm r \cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \theta_1\right )} $$

By assumption, $f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$ is even so

$$r=f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)=f(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$$

And the points

$$(f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta),\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)=(r, \frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$$

$$(f(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta),\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)=(r, \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$$

are symmetric because they are each on one of the lines $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\pm \theta_1$, and have the same $r$ (and also $y$) coordinate.

**Proof of** $f$ odd $\implies$ for every polar point $\left ( f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta), \frac{\pi}{2} +\theta \right )$ on the graph of $f$ there is another point on the graph of $f$, $\left ( f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta), \frac{\pi}{2} -\theta \right )$, symmetric to the first point relative to the $y$ axis.

Consider polar point

$$\left (f(-\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta), -\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta \right )$$

use $f$ odd

$$=\left (-f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta), -\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta \right )$$

use $(1)$

$$=\left (f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta), \frac{\pi}{2} -\theta \right )$$

$\implies$ $\left (f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta), \frac{\pi}{2} -\theta \right )$ is on the graph of $r=f(\theta)$.

But so is $\left (f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta), \frac{\pi}{2} +\theta \right )$

These two points are symmetric relative to the $y$ axis.

Now, considering the original question, the function $f(\theta)=1-\alpha\sin{(\theta)}$ is not odd, but condition $1$ above is satisfied:

$$f(\frac{\pi}{2} + \theta)=1-\alpha\sin{(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)}=1-\alpha\sin{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)}=f(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta)$$

Therefore, the graphs of $f(\theta)=1-\alpha\sin{(\theta)}$ are symmetric relative to the $y$ axis.